# why factory don't work properly between the directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I make two directives .To communicate between two directives I used a factory .
but it not work properly ..I want to delete my text when I press delete button ..I take factory to do my task but it not working .I also try to take service .it also don't help

here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yenmira9J9XpjscQzRoX?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <script>
      angular.module('app',[]).directive('a',function(){

     return {
    restrict :'E',
    scope:{},
    templateUrl:'a.html',
    controller:'ts',
    controllerAs:'vm'
  }

      }).controller('ts',function(sharedService){
        var vm=this;
        vm.delete=function(){
          alert('--');
          sharedService.deletepro();
        }

      }).directive('b',function(){

     return {
    restrict :'E',
    scope:{},
    templateUrl:'b.html',
    controller:'bb',
    controllerAs:'vm'
  }

      }).controller('bb',function(sharedService){
        var pm=this;
        pm.message= sharedService.sendData();

      }).factory('sharedService', function() {
    var data = {};

    function deletepro(){
        data = {};
    }

    function sendData(){
        var obj = {name:"pQr"};
        data = obj;
        return data;
    }

    return {
        sendData: sendData,
        deletepro: deletepro
    };
});
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your controller is first initialized, `data` and `vm.message` reference the same object, but when you run `deletepro` then `data` references a new object, but `vm.message` still references the old one.

If you want to pass data in this way, you must never replace `data` with a new object (otherwise, controllers will have to get the new object again).

Instead of `data = {};`, try `data.name = '';`

Comment: thanks it works here but when I use same concept here http://plnkr.co/edit/NWAu49i0D0q5V0jzuis8?p=preview  .it not work why ?

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting that it will update because `data` is a shared reference. But you are resetting it to `{}`, which breaks the reference. You instead need to modify it:

```
function deletepro(){
    for(var prop in data){
       delete data[prop];
    }
}
```

Also, keep in mind `a` and `b` are both real html tags, not sure if there are any issues ovewriting the standard `<a href=""></a>`,